# Scheduling Jasper report server

Tags: jasperserver

I have a report which is excel export.Due to high volume of data it shows me "**exceeded the limit of 500 maximum pages.**" Error and won't see the Export option enabled.
I tried to schedule the report with both success and failure notifications emails but didn't receive any :(

Is this because of lot of data ?

Any info or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!
Manasa

Comment: You should check the jasperserver logs as well to see the error. One of the reasons could be that you did not setup smtp server info correctly to properties file. Other as you told could be because of a lot of data.

You can check logs and put more concrete question points here.

Comment: Sorry for late reply ! :/ It's because of of large amount of data. I ran the report for weekly then it showed up. (y)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the maximum page limit by setting `net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages` property.

Example:

> net.sf.jasperreports.governor.max.pages=1000